# Changing ActionBar background affects Navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I'm changing the ActionBar background in a fragment with a ScrollView. I have a ScrollView listener which changes the alpha of the items in the layered-list based on the scroll distance. The action bar actually works great. However, the Navigation Drawer background gets affected by this alpha change and I have no idea why; the nav drawer background becomes invisible. I can reproduce this easily on a Nexus 7 running Android L but it doesn't always happen for some 4.4 devices.

The main part is:

```
ActionBar actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
LayerDrawable mActionBarBg = (LayerDrawable) getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_actionbar);
if (mActionBarBg != null) {
         setActionBarBgAlpha(0);
         actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(mActionBarBg);
}
```

Alpha calculator is this:

```
scrollView.setOnScrollChangedLitstener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {
         @Override
         public void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
             t = Math.max(t, 0);
             endpointHeader.setTranslationY(endpointHeader.getTop() + (t * 0.25f));
             mScrollAlpha = (int) Math.min(alphaToHeightRatio * t, 255);
             updateActionBarElemsAlpha(mScrollAlpha);
                    }
});
```

Couple of other methods:

```
private void updateActionBarElemsAlpha(int updatedAlpha){
    if(mActionBarTitleColor != null){
        mActionBarTitleColor.setAlpha(updatedAlpha);
        mActionBarTitleView.setTextColor(mActionBarTitleColor.getColor());
    }

    setActionBarBgAlpha(updatedAlpha);
}

private void setActionBarBgAlpha(int alpha){
    if(mActionBarBg != null){
        mActionBarBg.getDrawable(1).setAlpha(alpha);
        mActionBarBg.getDrawable(2).setAlpha(alpha);
    }
}
```

background_actionbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:drawable="@drawable/gradient" />
<item android:drawable="@color/grey_divider"/>
<item android:bottom="2dp"
    android:drawable="@color/White"/>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always mutate drawables before changing any attributes, otherwise you'll end up modifying the cached state which is by default shared across all instances.

```
if (mActionBarBg != null) {
    mActionBarBg.mutate();
    mActionBarBg.getDrawable(1).setAlpha(alpha);
    mActionBarBg.getDrawable(2).setAlpha(alpha);
}
```